# How to perform group by and count in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i've this table

```
-----------------------------
id | blog_link | source
-----------------------------
 1 | blog_one  | facebook
 2 | blog_one  | twitter
 3 | blog_two  | twitter
 4 | blog_four | unknown
 5 | blog_four | facebook
 6 | blog_four | twitter
-----------------------------
```

now i want to do bit analysis on this and i want out put to be like this

```
----------------------------------------
blog_link  | facebook | twitter | unknown
----------------------------------------
blog_one   | 1        | 1       | 0
blog_two   | 0        | 1       | 0
blog_three | 1        | 1       | 1
----------------------------------------
// above nos represent number of times facebook, twitter or unknown were the source
```

i've table ready on mysql i want to do how can i show table two using codeigniter on front-end, I now we can use group by and count but i'm not able to put the proper logic.

Comment: I would use a query similar to that suggested by @Abhik Chakraborty and simply use `$this->db->query()` be sure to escape any user input as it is not escaped in the `query()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query, but not sure how you can use it as active record but the plain query could be used as

```
select 
blog_link, 
coalesce(sum(source='facebook'),0) as facebook,
coalesce(sum(source='twitter'),0) as twitter,
coalesce(sum(source='unknown'),0) as unknown
from table_name group by blog_link ;
```